# Calculate direction and velocity based horizontal and vertical velocity

Tags: java, point, angle, direction

I'm currently working on a game in Java and I want to calculate the direction and the directional velocity from horizontal and vertical velocity which is supplied with all game objects. I would like to have a method like the one bellow to calculate the direction/angle the object is moving towards (based on it's horizontal and vertical velocity);

```
public double getAngle() {
    // Calculate angle/direction from the horizontal and vertical speed here
    return angle;
}
```

Of course, I'd need a similar method to calculate the directional velocity of an object based on it's horizontal and vertical velocity.

*Note: At the time I asked this question I didn't learned anything about geometry/trigonometry because I was in 2nd or 3th class.*

Comment: This is high-school geometry/trigonometry.  If you are making a game that involves geometry, I would strongly suggest recapping the maths, otherwise it's not going to be a productive experience.

Comment: Agree with Oli. Why not check out a review of basic trigonometry and then first try to code your methods yourself. Then if you get stuck, come back with your code attempts, and we'll be in a much better position to be able to help you.

Comment: [Wikipedia on Converting between polar and Cartesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates)

Comment: I already found the solution!

Comment: Your `angleVelocityToXYVelocity` function doesn't work properly if `vy` needs to be negative.

Comment: No, I tested it with a few different variables, and I took my calculator and calculated them by hand first. It works fine for me. When I set x to 3 and y to 4 and I convert those two to the angle and velocity, and I convert them back using the third funtion I still get the same values I used in x and y.

Comment: @Tim: Like I said, Try it with vy negative.

Comment: I did, it works for me. Even if x is positive or negative. I tried it with -4 and -5678 and it works for me. Check out this image; [http://d.pr/LY9e](http://d.pr/LY9e)

Comment: Do not update the question with the solution, post a solution *as an answer* and then accept that answer if it solves your problem.  I've done it for you in this case (and marked as CW so that I don't get rep from your answer) but you really should provide your own answer.

Comment: Thanks for posting my solution for me, I don't have enough reputations to post it myself, I really hate that. So thats the reason I didn't posted it myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Solution by Tim Visee](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9760950/1):

---

This is the solution I found after testing some things.
I made three functions, the first two could be used to calculate the angle and the velocity from // vertical and horizontal speed. The third function could be used to calculate the horizontal and the vertical velocity from the angle and the velocity.

```
public static double getAngle(double vx, double vy) {
    return Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(vy, vx));
}

public static double getVelocityWithAngle(double vx, double vy) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vx, 2) + Math.pow(vy, 2));
}

public static void angleVelocityToXYVelocity(double angle, double velocity) {
    double vx = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * velocity;
    double vy = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(velocity, 2) - Math.pow(vx, 2));

    System.out.println("vx: " + vx + " vy: " + vy);
}
```

Please note that the third function prints the results into the console since it returns two values.

Answer (score 5):

I think

```
angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(verticalSpeed,HorizontalSpeed) )
```

should work

Getting velocity from angle is not possible. Because there can be multiple values of vertical and horizontal speed that can give the same angle.

Comment: For a start, `tan` turns an angle into a ratio.  Also, what if horizontalSpeed = 0?

Comment: It still won't handle horizontalSpeed = 0.  Also, it can only resolve two quadrants, not all 4 (`atan(1/1) == atan(-1/-1)`).

Comment: Changed to atan2 ....that can handle horizontal speed = 0 and other cases you mentioned

Comment: The use of atan2 is incorrect. It should be atan2(yChange, xChange). Atan2 handles when xChange=0, and gives the angle on all quadrants.

Comment: I already found the solution. Also the inversed way and the way to find the velocity. I'll post them here now

Comment: Here's my solution, it fully works. I can't answer my own question stupid reputations. Please edit your post to the solution I found and I'll mark it as the answer.
[link](http://pastie.org/3623303)